# Is it possible to run Minitest tests within Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublime-text-2

[This package](https://github.com/maltize/sublime-text-2-ruby-tests) allows you to run rspec and some other testing frameworks' tests from within Sublime Text 2.  Is there a similar method for testing Minitest tests?  I haven't been able to find anything conclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, I'm using Sublime Text 2 + [RubyTest](https://github.com/maltize/sublime-text-2-ruby-tests) package with rails 4.1.5/ruby 2.1.2 but it should work on any other rails 4+ version.

In Sublime, go to `Preferences > Package Settings > RubyTest > Settings - Default`
or just search for `RubyTest.sublime-settings`.

You have to adjust paths for ruby_unit commands (these work with minitest)

`"run_ruby_unit_command": "rake test {relative_path}",` 
`"run_single_ruby_unit_command": "rake test {relative_path} {test_name}",`

if you are using spring you can modify add `spring` ahead of each rake

`"run_ruby_unit_command": "spring rake test {relative_path}",` 
`"run_single_ruby_unit_command": "spring rake test {relative_path} {test_name}",`

or `bin/rake` if you have spring bin-stubbed

`"run_ruby_unit_command": "bin/rake test {relative_path}",` 
`"run_single_ruby_unit_command": "bin/rake test {relative_path} {test_name}",`

Save the file, and maybe restart sublime (I didn't have to) and it should work.

Comment: haven't tried yet but seems sensible